# I am not able to store MySql Timestamp in Android SqlLite as Long

Tags: android, sqlite, gson, android-volley, android-room

**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2018-04-19 21:42:21**
while app fetch timestamp as String using gson.fromJson(response,User[].class)

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @TypeConverters({JConverter.class})
private Date date_added;

public Date getDate_added() {
    return date_added;
}

public void setDate_added(Date date_added) {
    this.date_added = date_added;
}
```

**and my JConverter class is**

```
public class Converters {

@TypeConverter
public static Date fromTimestamp(Long value) {
    return value == null ? null : new Date(value);`enter code here`
}
@TypeConverter
public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
    return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
 StringRequest getTable = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("tagg", response); //response is correct
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        users = gson.fromJson(response,User[].class);//exception occurs here
                        userDatabase.userDao().fillUsers(users);
.....
```

JSON response

```
[{"name":"jayesh","date_added":"2018-04-19 21:42:21"},{"name":"marathe","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:37:17"},{"name":"sagar","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:37:50"},{"name":"omkar","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:37:58"},{"name":"vedant","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:38:04"},{"name":"kalpesh","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:38:14"},{"name":"ashay","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:38:21"},{"name":"ameya","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:38:28"},{"name":"abhishek","date_added":"2018-04-19 22:38:34"}]
```

EXCEPTION

--------- beginning of crash

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.dell.testingapplication, PID: 4297
                  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2018-04-19 21:42:21
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:81)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:66)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814)
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:779)
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:728)
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:700)
                      at com.example.dell.testingapplication.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:44)
                      at com.example.dell.testingapplication.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:38)
                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-04-19 21:42:21"
                      at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:358)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:79)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:66) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:779) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:728) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:700) 
                      at com.example.dell.testingapplication.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:44) 
                      at com.example.dell.testingapplication.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:38) 
                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78) 
                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30) 
                      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: show your JSON and full exception stacktrace

Comment: i have added it

Comment: you should add TypeConvertor annotation on top of class, not field I guess.

Comment: which class User class?